# Удалить группы с неполным циклом

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Итак, есть исходный DF.
Первый столбец показывает этап , полный цикл 1-5 . Если вдруг в выборке не полный цикл, то удаляются все наблюдения неполного цикла.
То есть на входе есть:

```
Time    X1  X2
1   5   5
2   6   6
3   4   4
4   6   5
5   5   5
1   5   6
2   6   5
3   5   6
1   4   6
2   6   5
3   5   5
4   6   5
5   5   5
```

Второй цикл неполный: 1-3, поэтому удаляются все их наблюдения. А на выходе получается:

```
Time    X1  X2
1   5   5
2   6   6
3   4   4
4   6   5
5   5   5
1   4   6
2   6   5
3   5   5
4   6   5
5   5   5
```

Comment: Значения в столбце “Time” в одной группе строго неубывающие?

Comment: Да, строго  неубывающие

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [13]: res = df.groupby(df['Time'].diff().fillna(1).lt(1).cumsum()).filter(lambda x: len(x)>=5)

In [14]: res
Out[14]:
    Time  X1  X2
0      1   5   5
1      2   6   6
2      3   4   4
3      4   6   5
4      5   5   5
8      1   4   6
9      2   6   5
10     3   5   5
11     4   6   5
12     5   5   5
```

Пошагово:

```
In [16]: df['Time'].diff().fillna(1)
Out[16]:
0     1.0
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     1.0
5    -4.0
6     1.0
7     1.0
8    -2.0
9     1.0
10    1.0
11    1.0
12    1.0
Name: Time, dtype: float64

In [17]: df['Time'].diff().fillna(1).lt(1)
Out[17]:
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5      True
6     False
7     False
8      True
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
Name: Time, dtype: bool

In [18]: df['Time'].diff().fillna(1).lt(1).cumsum()
Out[18]:
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     2
9     2
10    2
11    2
12    2
Name: Time, dtype: int32
```

далее мы можем группировать DataFrame по результату предыдущих манипуляций...